# Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined not matching

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am still learning php/pdo. I am doing an update to a table. I am able to fetch a specific row from a display page,

```
$id = $_GET['id'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM aeroplane WHERE aeroplaneID=:aeroplaneID"; 
$query = $pdo->prepare($sql); 
$query->execute(array(':aeroplaneID' => $id)); 

while($row = $query->fetch()) 
{ 
$aeroplaneName = $row['aeroplaneName'];
$aeroplaneTopSpeed = $row['aeroplaneTopSpeed'];
$aeroplaneRange = $row['aeroplaneRange'];
$planeMakerID = $row['planeMakerID']; 
}
```

but when attempting to update the row I get:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message
>   'SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined

Now, I have checked the number of parameter I am passing and their names for some typo, or are my bind values wrong? This is my update code:

```
$sql = "UPDATE aeroplane SET aeroplaneName=:aeroplaneName, aeroplaneTopSpeed=:aeroplaneTopSpeed, aeroplaneRange=:aeroplaneRange, planeMakerID=:planeMakerID WHERE aeroplaneID=:aeroplaneID";

$query = $pdo->prepare($sql); 

$query->bindparam(':aeroplaneID', $id); 
$query->bindparam(':aeroplaneName', $aeroplaneName);
$query->bindparam(':aeroplaneTopSpeed', $aeroplaneTopSpeed);
$query->bindparam(':aeroplaneRange', $aeroplaneRange);
$query->bindparam(':planeMakerID', $planeMakerid);
$query->execute();
```

and this is the code for sending the update:

```
<td><input type="hidden" name="id" value=<?php echo $_GET['id'];?></td> 
<td><input type="submit" name="update" value="Update"></td>
```

but instead of updating, its deleting the row, and my delete code is on a completely different page.

Comment: `:` is come after `=` at `:=aeroplaneTopSpeed`

Comment: thanks for pointing that out, but now if do an update, its deleting the row, I haven't changed anything else on the rows above except for the change of the =:

Comment: Have you write any delete code in between???

Comment: my delete code is on completely different page

Comment: this code is from my display page:

echo "<td><a href=\"edit.php?id=$row[aeroplaneID]\">Edit</a> | <a href=\"delete.php?id=$row[aeroplaneID]\" onClick=\"return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')\">Delete</a></td>";

so the edit and delete pages are different

Answer (score 0):

there is your typo:

```
[...] aeroplaneTopSpeed:=aeroplaneTopSpeed [...]
```

change it to `=:`

Comment: yeah, @saty pointed that out, but now when I update, it deletes the row, even though the delete code is on a different page

Comment: hm, i can only guess that you need to doublecheck your edit.php if it either somehow calls your delete code or includes your delete.php

Comment: yeah, going through it now